# How to use "ab" with time expressions in German?

Tags: english-to-german, preposition, time

> As of tomorrow I'll be on vacation for three days.

Which one is correct to say?

> 1. Ab morgen werde ich für drei Tage in Urlaub sein.
> 2. Ab morgen bin ich in Urlaub für drei Tagen.

Thank you.

Comment: The first. The second is little unskilful and strictly spoken wrong tense. "Ab" translates to "From ... on ...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both sentences are possible. The second one has two little flaws.

1.

> Ab morgen werde ich für drei Tage in Urlaub sein.

This says that you are going to be on vacation (for three days) starting tomorrow.

*Ab morgen werde ich [für drei Tage] in Urlaub sein.*

2.

> Ab morgen bin ich in Urlaub für drei Tage<s>n</s>.

One would usually say

> Ab morgen bin ich für drei Tage in Urlaub.

That's also right. It starts tomorrow and then you are on vacation for three days. So present tense is right and in German it's usual to use present tense for statements about the future.

If you are going to visit your mother tomorrow, you would rather say

> Morgen besuche ich meine Mutter.

than

> Morgen werde ich meine Mutter besuchen.

Both are right but future tense is usually used if the thing that you are talking about is not totally certain.

Comment: Is it just me, or does "in Urlaub" sound somewhat unusual here? Personally, I'd definitely say "im Urlaub".

Comment: Both are [correct and usual](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Urlaub).